# The attachable property HtmlSource was not found in type WebViewExtension

Tags: xaml, mvvm, uwp, callisto

I found this source at [Callisto](https://github.com/timheuer/callisto/blob/master/src/Callisto/Extensions/WebViewExtension.cs) for WebView as WebViewExtension method. This same method was working fine in windows 8.1 apps and now when I try to use in universal windows apps then it is giving me this error.

> The attachable property HtmlSource was not found in type
>   WebViewExtension

I  am using this inside a user control with this syntax.

```
<WebView x:Name="ContentView"
Margin="15,10,10,10"
callisto:WebViewExtension.HtmlSource="{Binding SelectedFeedItem.Content}"/>
```

Source of WebViewExtension method is [here](https://github.com/timheuer/callisto/blob/master/src/Callisto/Extensions/WebViewExtension.cs).

Update:
Just to make sure I haven't messed up my xmlns declarations.
1. I have a common folder `common` and in inside I have a class called `Callisto.cs` file with the same source copied and no change.
2. In my xmlns: declaration I have `xmlns:callisto="Myrssapp.Win10.Common"`
Below is the image. 
[image]

Comment: Use a disassembler to look at the version in the assembly you're linked to.

Comment: @will I still get the same error even if I start a brand new project with my own implementation of this same code for HtmlSource. Something with Windows 10 Universal Apps or VS2015 is making it to not work.

Comment: Perhaps the type on which the property is defined isn't the same as the w10UA's WebView?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my issue and I don't know why it worked in Win 8 or I must have changed something. The mistake was in the xmlns: statement.

instead of
`xmlns:callisto="Myrssapp.Win10.Common"`

it should be
`xmlns:callisto="using:Myrssapp.Win10.Common"`
I missed the `using` keyword.